Isometries as a subgroup of conformal diffeomorphisms
I have a question that, if true, does not seem trivial to prove, but if false, I am unable to find a counterexample. The question is as follows:
Given a 3-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$, is the group of isometries
$\text{Isom}(M)$ a normal subgroup of the group of conformal diffeomorphisms $\text{Conf}(M)$? In the space forms it seems, it is. Thank you in advance for your responses.

Have you tried the direct computation? Like, if you take $\phi$ a conformal diffeo, $\psi$ an isometry, and check if $\phi^{-1}\circ\psi\circ\phi$ is an isometry. That should give you a hint of what to expect.

Yes, I did! I direct computation shows that $\phi^{-1}\circ \psi \circ \phi$ has a conformal factor of $\lambda_p \lambda_{\psi(p)}$ where $\lambda$ is the conformal factor of $\phi$.  It should not be normal in general but I think there is a relationship between these two groups that I don't quite understand.
